# Выражение "всех собак вешать"

Tags: фразеология

Все валить на одного человека — "вешать на него всех собак". А откуда пошло это выражение? Почему именно собак?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это очень простая загадка. ;)
Речь о колючках, репейнике. Их-то и называли собаками.

[ИСТОРИЯ СЛОВ - Вешать собак | wordhist.narod.ru](http://wordhist.narod.ru/veshat_sobak.html)

Другие версии после виноградовской всерьёз не рассматриваю.

Comment: Репейник можно назвать собакой за цепкость, но незаслуженные обвинения нельзя впрямую сравнить с собачьей хваткой?? Неопубликованная заметка Виноградова со ссылкой на одиночное мнение Соловьева по совершенно иному поводу выдается за истинное объяснение! Я извиняюсь - это какое-то фуфло... Цитата :  
>Историк С. М. Соловьев в своих «Записках» так отзывался о проф. П. М. Леонтьеве, классике, друге М. Н. Каткова: «Цепкость была отличительным качеством Леонтьева: вцепится во что-нибудь — не отстанет; собака (`репейник') есть лучшее для него подобие»

Comment: Прошу модераторов отменить принятие ответа за полной недоказанностью, ибо абсурд полный.

Answer (score 1):

Бабушка мне так и говорила: "Опять всех собак навешала", когда репьи чистила.

Comment: Бабушка молодец! У меня в детстве тоже была бабушка)